# SQL - How do I select rows from one table depending on data from two other tables?

Tags: sql, multiple-tables

I have an SQL question. It's a simple problem, but I'm not an SQL guy at all.

Here is the situation, I have three tables:

```
CUSTOMER(
    PK(customer_id)
)

LOAN(
    PK(loan_id),
    customer_it,
    behavior_id
)

BEHAVIOR(
    PK(behavior_id),
    unpaid_number
)

// PK(x): x is a primary key.
```

I would like to select all of the `CUSTOMERs` who have an `unpaid_number >= 1`.

Can anybody show me a way to work this around?

Thanks

Comment: This looks very much like homework. I agree with apomene's answer, but you could have shown what you have tried already. This is a very basic task, that is easy to figure out using a beginners tutorial.

Comment: Why questions like this still receive answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use inner join

SELECT c.* FROM CUSTOMER c INNER JOIN LOAN l ON l.customer_id = c.Customer_id INNER JOIN BEHAVIOR b ON b.behavior_id = l.behavior_id WHERE unpaid_number >=1

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for `INNER JOIN`. Use like:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER c
INNER JOIN LOAN l ON c.customer_id = l.customer_it
INNER JOIN BEHAVIOR b ON b.behavior_id = l.behavior_id
WHERE b.unpaid_number>=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you want all customers, you presumably want one row per customer, regardless of the number of matching rows in behavior.

That would suggest using `exists` or `in`:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where exists (select 1
              from loan l join
                   behavior b
                   on b.behavior_id = l.behavior_id
              where b.unpaid_number >= 1 and
                    l.customer_id = c.customer_id
             );
```

This is particularly important if you are considering using `select distinct`.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try below code

```
SELECT c.*
FROM CUSTOMER c
INNER JOIN LOAN l
    ON l.customer_id = c.Customer_id
INNER JOIN BEHAVIOR b
    ON b.behavior_id = l.behavior_id
WHERE  unpaid_number >=1
```

Answer (score 1):

try this?

```
SELECT LOAN.customer_it FROM LOAN
WHERE LOAN.behavior_id IN
    (SELECT BEHAVIOR.behavior_id
    from BEHAVIOR where BEHAVIOR.unpaid_number>=1)
```